# Running Drush Launcher on Windows

Tags: drush

When I run Drush in the command line on my Windows 10 computer or Windows Server 2016 servers, I get the following error:

```
drush : The term 'drush' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ drush
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (drush:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've downloaded drush launcher and made sure that it was located in my PATH. Why is this error message showing and how do I get passed it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message occurs because the command must be `drush.phar` and prefaced by the `php` command. In the same folder as Drush Launcher, you'd have to run `php drush.phar` to get it to work. Elsewhere, you'd have to run `php /path/to/drush.phar` (which can be just as, if not more, annoying that `vendor/bin/drush`).

To get it to work, create a folder called `drush.bat` in the same folder as `drush.phar` and include the following two lines of code:

```
@echo off
php %~dp0\drush.phar %*
```

This file is executed by the command `drush` since it is in your PATH and will then execute the proper `php` command passing the correct parameters. You'll then be able to run drush from anywhere on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the file name of drush.phar to just drush? After that put it in your path.

I just got it working for me on windows 10. I downloaded drush.phar from: https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher/releases/tag/0.6.0

Then I changed the name of the file to just drush and put it in my system and user path and now I can call drush from composer built drupal site.